# command for printing only what has been specified as A or B

Tags: macros

Suppose I have a document like the following:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newcommand{MyCommandForPrintingOnly}{...}
\newcommand{MyCommandForSpecifying}{...}

\MyCommandForPrintingOnly{A}

\begin{document}
\MyCommandForSpecifying{A}{Some A Text.}

\MyCommandForSpecifying{B}{Some B Text.}

\MyCommandForSpecifying{A}{Some A Text.}

\MyCommandForSpecifying{B}{Some B Text.}
\end{document}
```

And I want the following output:

> Some A Text.
>
> Some A Text.

How could I achieve this?

In other words: I am looking for a command that specifies something as "A" or "B" (or "C" ...) and another command which then *only prints what has been specified as "A"* in the output. Is there a way to include/exclude some content?

Alternatively only might think of what I am looking for as a way to "dynamically comment-out" certain lines in the document, so that I specify A or B in the preamble and every line within what has been specified as B is taken as if it was commented-out by a `%`.

(I think I have seen something similar on tex.sx before but I was unable to find it.)

Comment: Are you interested in a Lua-based solution (since it looks like you use LuaLaTeX)? Separately, will only `A` or `B` ever be true at one time, or could both `A` and `B` be true simultaneously?

Comment: @Mico: Of course I would be interested in a Lua-based solution. In my case (i.e., the case which triggered my posting the question here) it's strictly either-or. But I was already impressed (as usual) by egreg's answer. So, if you'd like to, please let me/us know how you would do it with Lua!

Comment: OK, I've gone ahead and posted a Lua-based solution.

Comment: To get a different perspective on conditional typesetting, see the ConTeXt page on [Modes](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain TeX, you could simply define

`\def\switch#1#2{#1}`

and in the document, use

`\switch{Some A text}{Some B text}`.

Redefine \switch to

`\def\switch#1#2{#2}`

to get the "B option".

You could expand this to have up to 8 options, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 7):

Another solution with the `\IfEq` macro from the [xstring](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring) package.

Define

```
\newcommand{\MyCommandForSpecifying}[2]{}
\newcommand{\MyCommandForPrintingOnly}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\MyCommandForSpecifying}[2]{\IfEq{##1}{#1}{##2}{}}}
```

and then use `\MyCommandForPrintingOnly{A}` or `\MyCommandForPrintingOnly{B}` depending on the lines you want to be printed.

MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xstring}


\newcommand{\MyCommandForSpecifying}[2]{}
\newcommand{\MyCommandForPrintingOnly}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\MyCommandForSpecifying}[2]{\IfEq{##1}{#1}{##2}{}}}

\MyCommandForPrintingOnly{A}

\begin{document}
\MyCommandForSpecifying{A}{Some A Text.}

\MyCommandForSpecifying{B}{Some B Text.}

\MyCommandForSpecifying{A}{Some A Text.}

\MyCommandForSpecifying{B}{Some B Text.}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 5):

With `expl3` it's easy to allow multiple choices.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyCommandForPrintingOnly}{m}
 {
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_clint_printing_list_clist { #1 }
 }
\clist_new:N \g_clint_printing_list_clist

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyCommandForSpecifying}{mm}
 {
  \clist_if_in:NnTF \g_clint_printing_list_clist { #1 }
   { #2 } % print the text
   { \__clint_ignore: } % do nothing but don't print two spaces
 }

\makeatletter % we need \@bsphack and \@esphack
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__clint_ignore: { \@bsphack\@esphack }
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Only A and C}
\MyCommandForPrintingOnly{A,C}

Some text \MyCommandForSpecifying{A}{Some A Text.} and other text

Some text \MyCommandForSpecifying{B}{Some B Text.} and other text

Some text \MyCommandForSpecifying{C}{Some C Text.} and other text

\section{Only B}
\MyCommandForPrintingOnly{B}

Some text \MyCommandForSpecifying{A}{Some A Text.} and other text

Some text \MyCommandForSpecifying{B}{Some B Text.} and other text

Some text \MyCommandForSpecifying{C}{Some C Text.} and other text

\end{document}
```

Note that the trick with `\@bsphack\@esphack` allows to avoid printing two spaces when an ignored text appears in a paragraph.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm missing something, this is exactly what the [`optional` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/optional) was designed for. Using this package your example would be written as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[A]{optional}

\begin{document}
\opt{A}{Some A Text.}

\opt{B}{Some B Text.}

\opt{A}{Some A Text.}

\opt{B}{Some B Text.}
\end{document}
```

Hopefully the usage is clear: `\MyCommandForSpecifying` is just `\opt`, and `\MyCommandForPrintingOnly` corresponds to passing the corresponding option text as an option when you load the package.

Answer (score 3):

Since it appears that you're using LuaLaTeX, here's a Lua-based solution. There are three TeX macros: `\settotrue` (set its argument, a Lua boolean, to "true"); `\settofalse` (set its argument, a Lua boolean, to "false"); and `\ConditionalPrint` (renamed from your `\MyCommandForSpecifying`).

The code is a bit "wordy" for the simple case at hand. I trust, though, that the wordiness will make it straightforward to adapt the code to more demanding settings. The code permits both "A" and "B" to be true simultaneously; it's up to the user to set one or the other (or both) to "true". The code also allows mid-document switches from A to B being true to them being false (and vice versa).

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luacode} % for "luacode" environment and "\luastring" macro
%% Lua-side code: function "conditional_print"
\begin{luacode}
-- s1, s2: strings; A, B: booleans
function conditional_print (s1,s2)
  if     s1=="A" and A then tex.sprint (s2)
  elseif s1=="B" and B then tex.sprint (s2)
  end
end
\end{luacode}
%% TeX-side code: macros \settotrue, \settofalse, and \ConditionalPrint
\newcommand\settotrue[1]{  \directlua{ #1 = true  } }
\newcommand\settofalse[1]{ \directlua{ #1 = false } }
\newcommand{\ConditionalPrint}[2]{%
   \directlua{ conditional_print ( \luastring{#1}, \luastring{#2} ) }}

\begin{document}
\settotrue{A} % set A to "true"; B is still "nil" (and thus "false")

\ConditionalPrint{A}{Some A Text.}

\ConditionalPrint{B}{Some B Text.}

\ConditionalPrint{A}{Some Addtional A Text.}

\ConditionalPrint{B}{Some Addtional B Text.}

\dots

\settofalse{A} \settotrue{B} % set A to false & B to true

\ConditionalPrint{A}{Some A Text.}

\ConditionalPrint{B}{Some B Text.}

\ConditionalPrint{A}{Some Addtional A Text.}

\ConditionalPrint{B}{Some Addtional B Text.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

For example this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\def\MyCommandForPrintingOnly#1{\gdef\MCFPO{#1}}
\def\MyCommandForSpecifying#1#2{\def\tmp{#1}\ifx\tmp\MCFPO #2\fi}

\MyCommandForPrintingOnly{A}

\begin{document}
\MyCommandForSpecifying{A}{Some A Text.}

\MyCommandForSpecifying{B}{Some B Text.}

\MyCommandForSpecifying{A}{Some A Text.}

\MyCommandForSpecifying{B}{Some B Text.}
\end{document}
```